# Turn off first row highlighting in Access 2007 or 2010 form

Tags: forms, ms-access, highlighting

I have an MS Access 2010 form with lots of subforms in datasheet view. By default, Access highlights the first row in each subform.

I would like to turn off (disable) highlighting of the first row on all of the subforms. I have been searching through the Access options and on forums but can't figure it how to do this. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about a table, then in a2010 in the ribbon you see this option:

[image]

However, if you talking about a datasheet form, then in the ribbon (datasheet tab) you should see this option here to turn off the highlighting.

[image]

It not clear if you talking about how to disable this hightlighi9ng, or only for the first row

(turning off highlight = yes, no problem)
(turning off ONLY highlight of first row = I don't think is possbile).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I do want to turn off highlighting of the first row, which you don't think is possible. I don't think it's possible either.